# Are undeclared variables legal in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, undeclared-identifier

I'm totally baffled by [some code](http://sourceforge.net/p/civ4betterai/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/CvGameCoreDLL/) I'm trying to compile. The compiler gives me several dozen "undeclared identifier" errors. They all seem to be local loop variables like this:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
```

I could easily fix it, but I don't understand how that code could have compiled for other people. And those files haven't been touched in ages.

Is there some kind of compiler flag for VC++ that automatically assumes `int` for undeclared variables? I couldn't find it. What gives?

---

A minimal full code example that replicates the problem:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ );
for ( i = 0; i < 100; i++ );
```

Comment: Which compiler is this code intended to be compiled with? Certain older, non-conforming compilers (most notably, Visual Studio 6) had the scope of the variable declared in a loop extend past the loop body, to the end of the enclosing block. So you could write `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {...} i = 42;` In that file you cite, variable `iK`is first declared and used on line 1784, and then reused past the body of that loop.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - I think you just found it... the code was originally compiled with VC7 (not sure which Visual Studio that is now). I hoped that VS2013 could compile too.

Comment: Try building with [`/Zc:forScope-`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84wcsx8x.aspx)

Comment: I don't think `/Zc:forScope` is right (see my answer).

Comment: @egrunin: I don't think so either - whereas `/Zc:forScope-` (with a minus sign at the end) that I suggested, likely is. [Live example](http://rextester.com/WZXPA25825)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is related to the scope of variables declared in a `for` statement.  The standard defines this scope to be restricted to the `for` loop itself.  But some compilers support non-standard legacy extensions that used to extend this scope to the enclosing bloc.

To compile such code with MSVC, add compiler switch /Ze

See [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b80153d8.aspx) for details.

A comment below suggests /Zc:forScope, but according to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b80153d8.aspx) that's not right.

By the way, G++ has a similar [`-fno-for-scope`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options) switch.

Comment: Incredible !  That's it !  The `for (int iK...)` in line 1784 of the example (in the comments of the question)  defines `iK` and this variable remains then defined until end of the enclosing that starts in 1783 and ends in 1842.

Comment: And for the records, G++ has `-fno-for-scope` for the same purpose.  In the manual, they refer to "old style code".  It's in fact very old style, as Stroustrup in the "C++ Programming langage" edition from 2000 already explains that the variable is not visible after the end of the for.

Comment: `/Ze` is [considered deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx), however `/Zc:forScope-` (note the minus sign!) did the trick. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a typed langage. One of the concequences is that you HAVE to declare variables before using them.

This seems strange to many but it contributes to have good coding practices, as weel as giving you errors when you do typos in your variables names.

On of the easy to understand concequences is that it helps you calling the good version of an overloaded function by checking the type of the arguments. This Check can be done at compile time which increase performance at runtime.

This is inherited from C which is choser to assembly then C++. Allocating variables means allocating the memory space on the stack.

You can always try and have a look at the `auto` keyword in c++11 and c++14, but before that make sure you know what a type is (like was is the difference between `1`, `1.0` and `1.f`)